# How to use and operator in conditions in Azure ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

```
"condition": "[equals(parameters('CreateNewNIC'), 'yes')]",
"condition": "[greaterOrEquals(parameters('VM_Instances'), 1 )]",
```

I have two conditions as shown above. But I want it to be in between AND conditions. Meaning both should get satisfied and then only execute the below script.

I want like something like `(Condition1 AND condition2)` `then` execute the rest of the script `else` don't execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try operator *and*:

```
"condition": "[and(equals(parameters('CreateNewNIC'), 'yes'), greaterOrEquals(parameters('VM_Instances'), 1 ))]"
```